# Travelling to Sharm el Sheikh (Egypt) - Price of alcohol

Tags: price, alcohol, nightlife, egypt, sharm-el-sheikh

I am going to Sharm el Sheikh in June and would like to check out the Naama Bay strip. What can I expect for the prices of alcoholic drinks in Egypt? I know it is a Muslim country and having been to Morocco I expect they will tend to be usually a bit more.

Can anyone confirm the prices, as compared to the UK?

Answer (score 8):

There is nothing much outside of the hotels, people tend to spend all of their time drinking and eating in the hotels.    Therefore all inclusive deals are common and well worth considering.

The hotel we stayed in charge well over £5 Sterling  for a bottle of coke if you were not on the all inclusive deal!

Sharm el Sheikh has nothing to offer apart from the weather, and diving.   There are not even many public beaches, so choose a hotel you like and don’t plan on stepping foot outside of the hotel.

Comment: Thanks for the message - £5 for a coke is well expensive! Is the Naama Bay not worth checking out? (I've never been so know very little about the place)

Comment: @Zabs, Sorry I don’t know about the Naama Bay, we went on honeymoon and had no intent of leaving the all exclusive hotel, otherwise we would not have gone to Sharm El Sheikh.

Comment: No worries - do you remember the name of the hotel, it is so hard to find reviews without thinking lots are fake (eg trip advisor) Thanks again

Comment: Sorry I can’t member the hotel, it was about 5 years ago, also it all comes down to the current manager at the hotel.   The local custom is for anyone that has any management responsibility to think they should not do any work, and just sit about while the “lowest of low” does the work.    E.g the gardening manager would stand there doing nothing while watching one of his staff water the plants.

Comment: £5 Sterling or £5 Egyptian?

Answer (score 1):

I was in Sharm El Sheikh on April and we stayed in Xperience Hotel which is all inclusive. Totally agree with others here. There is nothing else in Sharm El Sheikh besides the weather or diving. So it is better to stay inside the hotel.

You can drink any kind of alcoholic beverages for free in all inclusive hotels and there are some guys inside the hotel that you can ask and make a reservation for diving or other water attractions.

There are 2 famous streets outside but there is no attractions at all. Just some kind of hookah cafes. We only went to the Hard Rock Cafe and cocktails were like $12.